# can anybody explains the code and also recursion tree

Tags: recursion, data-structures, backtracking

i' am unable to make recursion tree
i saw many videos on this question but nobody is telling that after first left most leaf node completion
how the full recursion is made cause after there will two variable which index and j are updated. According to me if index is initialized in j then all elements are swapped by themselves.

how the code works please explain me

Example 1:

Input: nums = [1,2,3]
Output: [[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]]

```
class Solution {
    private:
    void solve(vector <int>nums, vector<vector<int>> &ans, int index){
        if(index >= nums.size()){
            ans.push_back(nums);
            return;
        }
    for(int j= index; j<nums.size(); j++){
        swap(nums[index] , nums[j]);
        solve(nums, ans, index+1);
        //backtrack

        swap(nums[index], nums[j]);
    }

    }
public:
    vector<vector<int>> permute(vector<int>& nums) {
        vector<vector<int>> ans;
        int index=0;
        solve(nums, ans, index);
        return ans;
    }
};
```

Comment: There is not *one* `index` variable here. There are many of them.

Comment: actually what i'm asking here is i'm unable to solve dry run of this code (backtracking)

Comment: What do you mean with "solve dry run"?

Comment: for index =0  the pointer goes to else part where nums[1,2,3] the 1 at 0th position swap from itself and then solve(nums, ans, index+1)=> index=1  like this ,,, for every iteration what will be the value of index and j so i want the recursion tree for this problem or if you are unable to understand the problem you can go to leetcode and see problem number 46

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> all elements are swapped by themselves.

Yes, the very first permutation that is generated is the original order of `nums`. This should be included, as that is one of the valid permutations.

Take a look at this loop:

```
    for(int j= index; j<nums.size(); j++){
        swap(nums[index] , nums[j]);
        solve(nums, ans, index+1);
        //backtrack
        swap(nums[index], nums[j]);
    }
```

The idea behind this loop is to have all values (from `index` to the end) take turns in taking the position at `index`, and then generate all permutations of the "rest" of the array (from `index+1` onwards).

The first iteration of the loop will choose `nums[index]` to take that position, so it actually doesn't have to move. So yes, the swap is doing nothing then. That's OK. But after the recursive call has returned, and the second swap is executed (which again does not move anything), we get to the next iteration of this loop:

Now `j` is `index+1`, and so the swap has an effect. It places the selected value (at index `j`) at index `index`, and now again a recursive call is made to generate all the permutations of the "rest" of the array.

#### Visualising

So for the example `nums = [1,2,3]`, we can represent what happens in a table, where the different recursion levels are each represented as a separate column. The value of `index` actually corresponds to the recursion depth (starting with 0), so I'll put that in the column headers. The last column is reserved to show the current state of `nums`. It is only filled in when something important happens, like a swap or pushing that result in the `ans` vector.

I'll abbreviate some of the quoted code, so that `swap(0, 2)` is short for `swap(nums[0],nums[1])`, and `push_back` short for `ans.push_back(nums)`, and `solve()` short for `solve(nums, ans, index+1)`...

| `index==0` | `index==1` | `index==2` | `index==3` | `nums` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `j=0` |  |  |  | `[1,2,3]` |
| `swap(0,0)` |  |  |  |  |
| `solve()` |  |  |  |  |
|  | `j=1` |  |  |  |
|  | `swap(1,1)` |  |  |  |
|  | `solve()` |  |  |  |
|  |  | `j=2` |  |  |
|  |  | `swap(2,2)` |  |  |
|  |  | `solve()` |  |  |
|  |  |  | `j=3` |  |
|  |  |  | `push_back` | `[1,2,3]` * |
|  |  | `swap(2,2)` |  |  |
|  |  | `j=3` |  |  |
|  | `swap(1,1)` |  |  |  |
|  | `j=2` |  |  |  |
|  | `swap(1,2)` |  |  | `[1,3,2]` |
|  | `solve()` |  |  |  |
|  |  | `j=2` |  |  |
|  |  | `swap(2,2)` |  |  |
|  |  | `solve()` |  |  |
|  |  |  | `j=3` |  |
|  |  |  | `push_back` | `[1,3,2]` * |
|  |  | `swap(2,2)` |  |  |
|  |  | `j=3` |  |  |
|  | `swap(1,2)` |  |  | `[1,2,3]` |
|  | `j=3` |  |  |  |
| `swap(0,0)` |  |  |  |  |
| `j=1` |  |  |  |  |
| `swap(0,1)` |  |  |  | `[2,1,3]` |
| `solve()` |  |  |  |  |
|  | `j=1` |  |  |  |
|  | `swap(1,1)` |  |  |  |
|  | `solve()` |  |  |  |
|  |  | `j=2` |  |  |
|  |  | `swap(2,2)` |  |  |
|  |  | `solve()` |  |  |
|  |  |  | `j=3` |  |
|  |  |  | `push_back` | `[2,1,3]` * |
|  |  | `swap(2,2)` |  |  |
|  |  | `j=3` |  |  |
|  | `swap(1,1)` |  |  |  |
|  | `j=2` |  |  |  |
|  | `swap(1,2)` |  |  | `[2,3,1]` |
|  | `solve()` |  |  |  |
|  |  | `j=2` |  |  |
|  |  | `swap(2,2)` |  |  |
|  |  | `solve()` |  |  |
|  |  |  | `j=3` |  |
|  |  |  | `push_back` | `[2,3,1]` * |
|  |  | `swap(2,2)` |  |  |
|  |  | `j=3` |  |  |
|  | `swap(1,2)` |  |  | `[2,1,3]` |
|  | `j=3` |  |  |  |
| `swap(0,1)` |  |  |  | `[1,2,3]` |
| `j=2` |  |  |  |  |
| `swap(0,2)` |  |  |  | `[3,2,1]` |
| `solve()` |  |  |  |  |
|  | `j=1` |  |  |  |
|  | `swap(1,1)` |  |  |  |
|  | `solve()` |  |  |  |
|  |  | `j=2` |  |  |
|  |  | `swap(2,2)` |  |  |
|  |  | `solve()` |  |  |
|  |  |  | `j=3` |  |
|  |  |  | `push_back` | `[3,2,1]` * |
|  |  | `swap(2,2)` |  |  |
|  |  | `j=3` |  |  |
|  | `swap(1,1)` |  |  |  |
|  | `j=2` |  |  |  |
|  | `swap(1,2)` |  |  | `[3,1,2]` |
|  | `solve()` |  |  |  |
|  |  | `j=2` |  |  |
|  |  | `swap(2,2)` |  |  |
|  |  | `solve()` |  |  |
|  |  |  | `j=3` |  |
|  |  |  | `push_back` | `[3,1,2]` * |
|  |  | `swap(2,2)` |  |  |
|  |  | `j=3` |  |  |
|  | `swap(1,2)` |  |  | `[3,2,1]` |
|  | `j=3` |  |  |  |
| `swap(0,2)` |  |  |  | `[1,2,3]` |
| `j=3` |  |  |  |  |

The execution flow is from top to bottom. If the code is placed in the second column, it means it is executing the second call of `solve`, with `index` equal to 1, ...etc.

Also note how each execution of `solve` (each column) has its own set of local variables. This means that when `j` is incremented by the `for` loop, this doesn't affect the value of `j` in any other execution context (other column).

I hope this clarifies it.

Comment: now i understood where i was going wrong

Comment: can you tell me where did you master this topic , that where the pointer points and all complier stuff? @trincot

Comment: At Leiden University, 1985.

Comment: is their is any book you want to suggest me for better understanding in the same.

Comment: Have a look at [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/5459839)